# Difference in serialized JSON in case of inheritance in Spring and Javax RS REST APIs

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jax-rs

I have one GET REST API implemented using Javax.ws.rs like below

```
@GET
    @Path("/test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @JacksonFeatures(serializationEnable = { SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT })
    @ApiOperation(value="Returns the metadata for the specified attributes.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
              @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error, Please check the logs for more details.")
            })
    public  List<Parent> getTest(@ApiParam(value="", required=false)@RequestParam(value ="name", required = false) String name)
            throws Exception {
        List<Parent> children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(new ChildA());
        children.add(new ChildB());
        children.add(new ChildA());
        return children;
    }


    @JsonTypeInfo(
            use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME,
            include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY,
            property = "type")
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildA.class, name = "childA"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = ChildB.class, name = "childB"),
        })
    interface Parent extends Serializable{

    }

    class ChildA implements Parent{

    }

    class ChildB implements Parent{

    }
```

It works pretty well and I get the following response for this API as expected:

```
[
    {
        "type": "childA"
    },
    {
        "type": "childB"
    },
    {
        "type": "childA"
    }
]
```

I am creating the same API using Spring 4.1.2. The business class and services will remain the same. For now I am just creating a new Spring Controller for this API:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test",method = RequestMethod.GET, produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @ApiOperation(value = "data", notes="some note.")
    @ApiResponses(value = {
              @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error, Please check the logs for more details.")
            })
    public  List<Parent> getTest(@ApiParam(value="", required=false)@RequestParam(value ="name", required = false) String name)
            throws Exception {

        List<Parent> children = new ArrayList<>();
        children.add(new ChildA());
        children.add(new ChildB());
        children.add(new ChildA());
        return children;
    }
```

Now this new API returns the following JSON:

```
[
    {},
    {},
    {}
]
```

I understand that this is happening due to type erasure feature of Java at compile time. Spring is not able to find out the parameterized type of the List and thus not able to add "type" in the serialized JSON.
But then how does this work with old Javax RS API and how can I fix this in new API without changing the returned JSON format

Answer (score 0):

This is actually a Jackson feature, not dependent on JAX-RS or Spring Boot.

In your Spring Boot app you can annotate the parent interface and child classes with the same @JsonTypeInfo and @JsonSubTypes annotations as before, and the type inference will work as before.  Jackson should already be included your Spring Boot app's dependency / classpath (via a parent POM.)

Comment: Parent and ChildA interface/class are common in this case so they are already annotated. Jackson is also included in Spring application. Somehow same child class is having "type" when serialized from old app but not when from Spring app.

Comment: @IshanRastogi I made a minimal spring boot controller from your example ([see gist here](https://gist.github.com/peekay/cd20489e3549729875fd9bed0944da34)) and it worked fine, so the problem seems elsewhere in the application, perhaps not related to Spring Boot per se.  I also tried a version with swagger / spring fox since you had API annotations (in case there was a conflict), and that worked fine as well.  I used Spring Boot 2.1.4-RELEASE, starter web.  Maybe try to isolate the problem by creating a similar minimal example from your fuller app?

Comment: Yes, it looks like that there is some problem with 2 different flows. May be serializer versions are different. I didn't have time to debug that so for now I am using ObjectMapper to create JSON string from Map and it works fine from there as I provide the information of Map key value types.